# Can't remove zonealarm

Tags: windows-vista, zonealarm

I have a version of zonealarm on vista32 that can't be uninstalled due to a bug in that version. I have the script to manually uninstall, but I can't take ownership on any of the files. I seem to remember doing this before, but can't now.

The owner of program files is trustedinstaller. I want to change it to administrators. So far, I haven't been able to do this. Do you know a way this can be changed? Nothing I have found works. I am logged into the administrator account.

Comment: Can you install a later version, then uninstall it instead?

Comment: I am very stubbon, and refuse to accept that I can't delete any file I want. But I am a couple hours into this nonsense and might try that.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing (install new.. uninstall). I want to learn more about trusted installers and what power they have over the file system. I have uber-power in that I can wipe the drive :+>

Answer (score 1):

Try [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html). This might solve your problem

Comment: I agree. Revo does a great job at removing stuff that is corrupt.

Comment: That's not required. I have full knowledge of the files to be deleted. I need to know how I can delete files. I have taken ownership of system32 as administrator, and ownership of the files, but vista is still refusing to delete the files. I need to solve the ownership problem and this has first priority now.

Comment: It's not so much of an uninstaller as it is a deep cleaner for things you don't want. If you try it and it doesn't work, here is a resource on [ownership](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-system-file-in-windows-vista/)

Comment: If it works (haven't tried it) the programmers know how to defeat NTFS security and I'd like to know how they do it while running on windows. I could not even delete the files by dual booting another version of windows, and you know they're not locked then. I think that only the signed installer by zonelabs can delete them (theory). I could use knoppix live cd and delete that way I guess.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comment on nrhine1's answer, may I suggest **[Lockhunter](http://lockhunter.com/)**:

It will show you what is locking a file and allows to stop the service/process. Unlike other programs of its kind it will not delete the file(s) but rather move them to the Recycle Bin if you wish to restore the file(s).

[image]

[image]

*Lockhunter is freeware, works with all Windows versions, 32-bit and 64-bit.*

Of course you can always from an external source that doesn't give a hoot about Windows permissions, e.g. a Linux Live distro!

Comment: Zonealarm is completely shut down, no processes are active. This is a permissions problem only. I can't even delete license.txt in it's program files directory. Administrator is the owner, has full permission except for 'special permissions'. So a trick has been done during install that I want to undo.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem trying to remove ZA from Windows 7.

Running the uninstaller from the *control panel* or using *revo uninstaller* caused  nasty crashes and the forced uninstaller option in *revo* didnt work either, even disabling *ZA* startup with *msconfig* didn't stop it from starting up.

What worked for me was booting in safe mode where I was able to uninstall the normal way from the control panel.